# Telnet with PHP - it works just with echo?

Tags: php, string, variables, telnet

I'm using PHPTelnet.php class (http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/) to get WAN IP from my router via telnet command. It goes like this:

```
require_once "PHPTelnet.php";

$telnet = new PHPTelnet();
$telnet->show_connect_error=0;

$result = $telnet->Connect('192.168.0.1','username','password');

switch ($result) {
case 0:
$telnet->DoCommand('sys ddns display', $result);
echo $result;
$telnet->DoCommand('exit', $exit);
echo $exit;
$telnet->Disconnect();
break;
```

It works. When i echo $result i can see many settings like this:

sys ddns display DDNS Status state = 0, flags = 1 pauseTime = 0, timerID = 0 startcnt = 2, stopcnt = 1 retrycnt = 0, eventqcnt = 0 socketID = -1 DomainName = eMail Address = update IP = **XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX** update time = 00:00:00 Thu. Jan. 01, 1970 retCode = good

Since i'm only intrested in getting the **XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX** (WAN IP) i do a preg_match to get the IP from $result. Here comes the problem. I always get this error:

> Undefined offset: 1

Basically it means that preg_match can't find any match. I use this code to match the IP:

```
$regex = '/\IP = ([^\"]*?)\ /';
preg_match($regex, $result, $matches);
```

It matches the IP properly. In fact if i try with something like this it works.

```
$result = "sys ddns display DDNS Status state = 0, flags = 1 pauseTime = 0, timerID = 0 startcnt = 2, stopcnt = 1 retrycnt = 0, eventqcnt = 0 socketID = -1 DomainName = eMail Address = update IP = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX update time = 00:00:00 Thu. Jan. 01, 1970 retCode = good tc> ";
$regex = '/\IP = ([^\"]*?)\ /';
preg_match($regex, $result, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The problem seems that the $result that comes directly from **$telnet->DoCommand('sys ddns display', $result);** can only be echoed but not used as string. Why? What's the point of this? How can i really get telnet responses as real variables?

Comment: Firstly the `[^\"]` doesn't seem to bare any relevance to the data you are searching (there are no double quotes anywhere in the string you show, so that will match anything), secondly the leading backslash in the regex also makes no sense (there is nothing to escape) and thirdly this seems like a needlessly complex way to find your public IP when you could just use something like http://whatismyipaddress.com/api (there are numerous services that offer the same functionality for free)

Comment: I know that regex is poorly made. I was just recycling it for testing purposes just to understand quickly if the script can really works. Anyway lol i know how to get my public IP :D What i'm doing is a more complex thing. I have an home server under a dynamic ip. Every 60 seconds via telnet a script gets the current public ip and, if it's changed, via API it also updates the A record of a real domain i have with a Registrar. In this way i can always get access to my home server, all my PC and even mobile phones by simply visiting home.mydomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. It was a problem with my lazy-regex. It works with this:

```
function GetIP($string)
{
    preg_match("/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/", $string, $matches);
    $ip = $matches[0];
    return $ip;
}
```